# WordPress: How to create upload image button inside author page - IMAGE COVER NOT AVATAR?

Tags: php, wordpress, banner, author, cover

I think search engines they are crazy :), 3 days of searching of how to create image uploader button in frontend for image cover/banner inside the author page, And all the results I have got talking about AVATAR :( OMG! HEY Google please I don't need AVATAR hehe!

In between a million plugins like buddypress, membership...etc!

But I don't need to use any plugin for just Profile Cover image!

I don't have or found any code yet, So please there are any way to make our users upload an image like a header or cover for their profile in the FrontEnd? Thanks.

Comment: Hi there! Have you tried using ACF plugin? By this plugin you can add a custom field on your author's page. And they also have this function called acf_form() (Source: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf_form/) which can make a frontend from.

Comment: Thank you, Yes I know ACF plugin, But I'm trying first to find some way to do it by coding instead of plugins!